# Python : how to write a the value of certain key into a file?

Tags: python

i have a list named "list". it contains two dictionaries.I am accessing these dictionaries as dict[count], dict[count+1].

Now i have to check a key is as version. Then i wrote the code as

```
filename = "output.txt"
fo = open(filename, "a")
for key1,key2 in zip(dict[count].keys(),dict[count+1].keys()):
   if key1 == 'version':
      # print "value of version:", (dict[count])[key]
      fo.write("value of version:",(dict[count])[key])
   if key2 == 'version':
      # print "value of version:", (dict[count+1])[key]
      fo.write ("value of version:", (dict[count+1])[key2])
```

Here i am able to print the value of version but i am unable to write into a file.

Errror: TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: fo.write("value of version:" **+** (dict[count])[key])

Comment: Thanks deathangle908. its working

Comment: Refrain from using dict and list as variable names. It is dangerous and will give unwanted results.

Comment: Don't use `list` or `dict` as variable names; those are the names of the built-in types `list` and `dict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do `file.write()` like you do `print()` passing in multiple objects to print separated by comma (as a tuple) , and that is the reason you are getting the error . You should use `string.format()` to format your string correctly.

Example -

```
filename = "output.txt"
fo = open(filename, "a")
for key1,key2 in zip(dict[count].keys(),dict[count+1].keys()):
   if key1 == 'version':
      # print "value of version:", (dict[count])[key]
      fo.write("value of version:{}".format(dict[count][key1]))
   if key2 == 'version':
      # print "value of version:", (dict[count+1])[key]
      fo.write ("value of version:()".format(dict[count+1][key2]))
```

Also, not sure why you need to do zip and all, you can simply do -

```
filename = "output.txt"
fo = open(filename, "a")
if 'version' in dict[count]:
    fo.write("value of version:{}".format(dict[count]['version']))
if 'version' in dict[count+1]:
    fo.write("value of version:{}".format(dict[count+1]['version']))
```

Answer (score 3):

**fo.write()** function must have only one argument. You provided two arguments so it did not work. Please see below line and use it.

```
fo.write("value of version:%s"%(dict[count])[key])
fo.write ("value of version:%s"%(dict[count+1])[key2])
```